# NextJs / Framer Motion: When using useViewportScroll I got this warning: Warning: useLayoutEffect does nothing on the server,

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, redux-toolkit, framer-motion

I am using NextJs with Framer Motion. Everything is working properly but I got this warning:

```
Warning: useLayoutEffect does nothing on the server, because its effect cannot be encoded into the server renderer's output format. This will lead to a mismatch between the initial, non-hydrated UI and the intended UI. To avoid this, useLayoutEffect should only be used in components that render exclusively on the client.
```

Comment: `useLayoutEffect` fires synchronously after DOM mutations. Using it while rendering server side will have no effect. If you really need to use `useLayoutEffect` you can exclusively render the component in the client. Pls share what exactly you are trying to do with it, so I can suggest some alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this will be get fixed in the upcoming framer-motion version.

From the GitHub conversation

> The React 18 upgrade in #1438 introduced a new useIsMounted hook, that
> that didn't use the useIsomorphicLayoutEffect. This resulted in a
> warning rendered serverside. Fix by replacing useLayoutEffect with
> useIsomprohicLayoutEffect

https://github.com/framer/motion/pull/1452

For a temporary fix, you can cancel rendering the the component if it is not client render, by adding such as

```
const [isLoaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
  setLoaded(true);
}, []);

if (!isLoaded) {
  return null;
}

return (
  ...your component
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Next does [SSR](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#server-side-rendering) which is why its throwing this warning as useLayoutEffect doesn't run on server.

Official [docs of useLayoutEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect):

> The signature is identical to useEffect, but it fires synchronously after all DOM mutations. Use this to read layout from the DOM and synchronously re-render. Updates scheduled inside useLayoutEffect will be flushed synchronously, before the browser has a chance to paint.